# Copy and paste without any HTML formatting

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

I have a webpage that has text in a tabular display with all the usual formatting for size color etc. I am trying to make it more convenient for my user to copy paste into an email/Word Doc or whatever. I am trying to make it so a simple copy/paste does what right clicking and selecting "paste special" then "plain text" does so it will loose the tabular/text formats.

So far I have somewhat managed to do this by using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Format() {
        var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var selection;
        selection = window.getSelection();
        var quotefrom = "<?php echo $book_text . ' ' . $chapter . ": < br > "; ?>";
        causevar copytext = quotefrom + selection;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.style.background = "white";
        body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
        newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
        selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
        }, 0);
    }
    document.oncopy = Format;
</script>
```

This actually masks rather than removes some formatting. For example the line:
newdiv.style.background = "white";
Simply takes any color highlighting and changes it to white so as long as the user is pasting into an email with a white background it appears to not have that format. This does however cause the tabular formatting to be removed and that is a good thing.

What I really want is to be able to do what a copy/paste into this text area here does... completely remove all formatting. I understand it isn't even close to being the same pasting here and pasting in a document that will allow the formatting but that doesn't stop me from trying to figure this out :)
Thanks for any suggestions you may have.